# Python networking and file I/O: Local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to implement a web server in Python and so far I can get "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" to display in my web browser, but after that my program stops with an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dest_file' referenced before assignment` error.

I'll add a comment in my code where the error is occurring.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Simple network socket demo - SERVER
#
# Set script as executable via: chmod +x server.py
# Run via: ./server.py <BASE> <PORT>

import socket
import sys
if not sys.version_info[:2] == (3,4):
 print("Error: need Python 3.4 to run program")
 sys.exit(1)
else:
 print("Using Python 3.4 to run program")
import argparse

def main():

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Project 1 Web Server for COMP/ECPE 177')
parser.add_argument('--version', help='Show program\'s version number and exit')
parser.add_argument('--base', action='store', help='Base directory containing website', metavar='/path/to/directory')
parser.add_argument('--port', action='store', type=int, help='Port number to listen on', metavar='####')
args = parser.parse_args()
#parser.print_help()
#print(args.port, args.base)


# Create TCP socket
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
except socket.error as msg:
    print("Error: could not create socket")
    print("Description: " + str(msg))
    sys.exit()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Bind to listening port
try:
    host=''  # Bind to all interfaces
    s.bind((host,args.port))
except socket.error as msg:
    print("Error: unable to bind on port %d" % args.port)
    print("Description: " + str(msg))
    sys.exit()

# Listen
try:
    backlog=10  # Number of incoming connections that can wait
                # to be accept()'ed before being turned away
    s.listen(backlog)
except socket.error as msg:
    print("Error: unable to listen()")
    print("Description: " + str(msg))
    sys.exit()    

print("Listening socket bound to port %d" % args.port)

while 1:
# Accept an incoming request
    try:
        (client_s, client_addr) = s.accept()
        # If successful, we now have TWO sockets
        #  (1) The original listening socket, still active
        #  (2) The new socket connected to the client
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Error: unable to accept()")
        print("Description: " + str(msg))
        sys.exit()

    print("Accepted incoming connection from client")
    print("Client IP, Port = %s" % str(client_addr))

    # Receive data
    try:
        buffer_size=4096
        raw_bytes = client_s.recv(buffer_size)
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Error: unable to recv()")
        print("Description: " + str(msg))
        sys.exit()

    string_unicode = raw_bytes.decode('ascii')
    print("Received %d bytes from client" % len(raw_bytes))
    print("Message contents: %s" % string_unicode)

    request = str.split(string_unicode)
    #print(request)
    hcmd = request[0]
    filep = request[1]
    protocol = request[2]
    print(filep)

    if filep == '/':
        filep = '/index.html'

    if hcmd == 'GET':
        try:
            try:
                dest_file = open(args.base + filep, 'rb')
            except (OSError, IOError) as msg:
                msg = 'HTTP/1.1 404 Request Not Found\r\n\r\n'
                statcode = 1 #404 request not found
                rb1 = bytes(msg, 'ascii')
                client_s.sendall(rb1)

            message_send = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n'
            statcode = 0 #200 OK
            rb2 = bytes(message_send, 'ascii')
            client_s.sendall(rb2)

            datasend = dest_file.read()  #<---- This is where the error occurs
            client_s.sendall(datasend)
            filename.close()
            print(dest)
            print(statcode)

        except socket.error as msg:
            msg2 = "Error: "
            sys.exit()

    else:
        message_send = 'HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented\r\n\r\n'
        statuscode = 2 #501 not implemented
        rb3 = bytes(message_send, 'ascii')
        client_s.sendall(rb3)
    client_s.close()

#Close both sockets
try:
   s.close()
except socket.error as msg:
   print("Error: unable to close() socket")
   print("Description: " + str(msg))
   sys.exit()

print("Sockets closed, now exiting")

if __name__ == "__main__":
sys.exit(main())
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dest_file = open(args.base + filep, 'rb')` is assigned inside the `try/except` block so if there is an exception it  will not be defined so `datasend = dest_file.read()` will cause the error as `dest_file` will not be assigned to anything.

set `dest_file = None` outside  and before the `try/except` block and use:

```
 if dest_file is not None:datasend = dest_file.read()
```

If `dest_file`  is `None` we had an exception or else everything is ok.

Comment: Thanks so much! I moved that line and the following 2 lines into an if statement and now the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you *try* to assign to `dest_file`:

```
try:
    dest_file = open(args.base + filep, 'rb')
except (OSError, IOError) as msg:
    msg = 'HTTP/1.1 404 Request Not Found\r\n\r\n'
    statcode = 1 #404 request not found
    rb1 = bytes(msg, 'ascii')
    client_s.sendall(rb1)
```

But if it fails—e.g., because the file specified doesn't exist—you continue on with the rest of the block anyway, with nothing assigned to `dest_file`. So, when you try to use it later, you get this exception.

You probably want to exit this block (maybe by `return`ing), or move the rest of the block into an `else:` clause on the `try:`.

Alternatively, you may have some fallback value you want to assign to `dest_file`—either some other file-like object, or just something like `None` that you can test for later—in the `except` block.